# PHP: how to get all defined variables inside exception_handler

Tags: php, exception

I'm working on a exception logging script, I use set_exception_handler() to handle uncaught exception.

Inside my custom exception handler, I use get_defined_vars() but it only return an array with a exception object, every variables created before exception thrown were disappear

```
$testing_var = 'testtesttest';

try {
throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");
} catch (Exception $e) {
var_dump(get_defined_vars()); // this could get $testing_var 
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

function exception_handler(exception)
{
 var_dump(get_defined_vars()); // no, it can't get $testing_var, exception object only
}

throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");
```

Comment: I think it might be possible with xdebug and the `collect_params` and `collect_vars` conf options.

Answer (score 1):

In the scope where you are calling `get_defined_vars()` the variable you are after is not defined, so of course it will not be returned. [from the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php):

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables, **within the scope that get_defined_vars() is called**.

What are you trying to achieve? In general you should pass all information needed to handle the exception to the exception when constructing it. possibly using a custom exception class:

```
<?php

// custom exception class
// could be extended with constructor accepting an optional context
class ContextAwareException extends Exception
{
    private $context;

    public function setContext($context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getContext()
    {
        return $this->context;
    }
}

function exception_handler($exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ContextAwareException) {
        $exception->getContext();
    } else {
        // we have no context
    }
}

/*
 * using this exception
 */

$testing_var = 'testtesttest';

$exception = new ContextAwareException("Error Processing Request");
$exception->setContext(get_defined_vars());
throw $exception;
```

Comment: you're right I can't get $testing_var from my handler's scope.
Unfortunately the handler is for uncaught exception, means the exception is throw by system and the type is unpredictable, but I still need those variables, is other way to achieve this?

Comment: it's indeed for uncaught exceptions, but this does not mean they are thrown by the system, it means they are not caught... You can throw your custom exception and not catch it. If you want this approach for exceptions thrown by third party code, I think you are out of luck.

Comment: FYI, I think you are searching for a solution for the wrong problem. maybe you should elaborate on why you want the variables of the exception's scope, this seems flawed by design.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternate way to do this. I'm also looking for exception solution but this one works for me. If you use errors instead of exceptions - it seems to work.

```
set_error_handler('test','handler');

class test {

    public static function handler($code, $error, $file = NULL, $line = NULL) {

        throw new Exception($error, $code, 0, $file, $line);

        return true;
    }
}

$testVar='carolines';

try { 
    trigger_error('megamsg');
}

catch(Exception $e) {

    var_dump($e);

    $vars=$E BLABLABLA

}
```

Find yourself how to extract from $e. But if you debug You will see in trace handler function call with $testVar variable